# Javascript (imported) Class is not defined, ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, webpack, babeljs

I need advice once again, in my project I'm using NodeJS, Webpack with babel-loader and I've split it into different files.

I keep getting the error :

```
ReferenceError: PlayerManager is not defined
```

PlayerManager is a Class that I imported in my main file :

```
import PlayerManager from './game/modules/PlayerManager';
import Player from './game/modules/Player';
import Game from './game/modules/Game';
```

It's weird cause if I check my compiled code in firefox's debugger, the classes are all there in my bundle file.

This is the line of code triggering this error:

```
this.playerManager = new PlayerManager(this.ctx);
```

Which is inside my Class file's constructor, imported before (see above)

```
export default class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.w = window.innerWidth;
        this.h = window.innerHeight;
        this.frames = 60; 
        this.resize();
        this.players = {};
        this.playerManager = new PlayerManager(this.ctx);
        ....
        ....
```

Now I call `new Game()` and error triggers...

What could cause the error?

Is using `new Class` inside another one's constructor wrong?

Comment: is `PlayManager` imported where `Game` class is defined?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, it's imported before Game class in my main js file

Comment: it needs to be imported inside "file" where Game class is trying to use it

Comment: @JaromandaX Adding this here too : Why it has to be imported in the single class file? Considering I'm importing all 3 classes in my main file, wouldn't this practice make the class to be declared twice when compiled?

Comment: I don't know "compilers" , maybe the "compiler" is broken - I do know if you wish to access an exported resource you need to `import` it in the module you use it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An import is only available in that particular file.

You need to import `PlayerManager` into the file where your `Game` class is defined.

Comment: sorry I was mixing things up... now my browser's console says `TypeError: _Player2.default is not a constructor` after I imported `import PlayerManager from './PlayerManager';` inside `Game` class, same import I have in my main file, but there it works, here no (?)..

Comment: You haven't shown us what PlayerManager looks like. It sounds like you forgot to export it as default.

Comment: @tremby this seems to have solved the `TypeError` problem. I'm a bit confused, why is it necessary to export the classes (I guess all of them at this point) as `default` ?

Comment: And also, a question popped in my mind, considering I'm importing in my main file all the classes (playermanager first, player and then game) why I have to import PlayerManager in Game class file to not receive a typeerror? (see coments in my op), I mean, am I not calling it twice this way? I thought it should work correctly importing all classes in the main file...

Comment: You don't export it as `default`, you make it the default export. `export default PlayerManager;`. This is what will be imported when you do `import LocalName from './game/modules/PlayerManager';`: whatever is the default export will now be `LocalName` (but obviously it makes sense to still call it `PlayerManager`. As for why you have to import it twice, you need to go read about ES6 modules. This is basic stuff. You're only importing it into the scope of the current file. No need to import it into your main file if you don't reference it there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) this problem is actually solved, although the program isn't drawing players, but that's another problem, no more console errors, im gonna mark your answer as correct, thanks again.